# Value issue in Float datatype in BigQuery, while loading data from AVRO and parquet into Bigquery tables

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, avro, parquet

I am facing a weird issue while loading data from AVRO/Parquet files in BigQuery using `bq` load job or by apache-spark dataframe.

Source files have float datatype with value 22.54 but after loading it to BigQuery its automatically changing to 22.540000915527344.

I tried with other file formats and using both directly `bq` load job and using spark dataframe but problem is still persists.
I am adding the details of both AVRO file data and BigQuery data after loading.

Please let me know if you have faced this issue and help me resolving this issue.

The AVRO schema is provided below:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "topLevelRecord",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "int"
  }, {
    "name" : "cp",
    "type" : "float"
  } ]
}
```

AVRO Data:

```
| id  | cp  |
|-----|-----|
|  1  |22.54|
```

BigQuery Data:

```
| id  | cp               |
|-----|------------------|
|  1  |22.540000915527344|
```

Comment: Have you try rounded the value ie: `ROUND(val, 2)` before inserting into your table?. If you round your value before inserting in your dataset table you should be able to preserve the 2 decimal places even if the column is FLOAT64.

Comment: If you are using a transfer job you can set the decimal types to 2.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely to have this type of error if you use `float` datatype (which uses 32 bits) vs `double` (64 bits).

The [float representation](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=050050046053052) of `22.54` is `22.54000091552734375`

If [you switch to double you get](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=050050046053052): `22.5399999999999991473487170879` which is closer to 22.54.

You see a difference between big query and avro because they use different rounding policy when displaying the data. But under the hood the data is the same. The conversion between the two systems should be loss less.

Comment: is there a way where we can get exactly same value as it is in AVRO. For our dataset, values could be 2 or more than 2 decimal places. We want precision of the value maintained.

Comment: The value in avro is `22.54000091552734375`, it is just that AVRO formats it to `22.54`. If you want more precision, you should switch from float to double. But you're still likely to get similar issues. The alternative is to use decimals, but they are not as widely supported. https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Decimal